# Strange behaviour of NSMutableAttributed string

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I am working on XCode 6.3 | Swift 1.2

Recently while working, I noticed that all initializers of `NSMutableAttributedString` return object of type `NSAttributedString`

Adding to that, although objects are of type `NSAttributedString`,  it rightly invokes (and code completes ) the methods of `NSMutableAttributedString` type.

Is any one aware of internals of this kind of behavior.

Comment: A lot of problems were fixed with Swift 2. It'll definitely make your life easier. Is there a particular reason why you haven't upgraded to Xcode 7?

Comment: Yes, The reason is, not all the libraries which I am using have updated their code to Swift 2. Also my app is waiting for Review and there are already 2 rejections. I do not want to risk updating my entire code base